# ion-slides don't show anything

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slide

I"m trying to do an app for android with ionic. I want to do a ion-slides for each item in my scope but nothing shows up.

```js
$scope.channels = [];

  $scope.options = {
  loop: false,
  effect: 'fade',
  speed: 500,
  }
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.$watch('data.slider', function(nv, ov) {
    $scope.slider = $scope.data.slider;
  })
```

```html
<ion-view title="home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="temperatureCtrl">
        <div>
            <h1>hello allz</h1>
            <div ng-init="init()"></div>
            <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider" > 
                <ion-slide ng-repeat="channel in channels">                
                    <h2><center>canal# {{channel.canal}}</center></h2>
                </ion-slide>                 
            </ion-slides>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I have used ionic slider but the link is very much good in ionic too. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think ion-slide is the wrong element within ion-slides

can you try what happens with ion-slide-pages ?

like this:

```
<ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider" > 
    <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="channel in channels">                
        <h2><center>canal# {{channel.canal}}</center></h2>
    </ion-slide-page>                 
</ion-slides>
```